# Matlab+GA: Simulated Binary Crossover (SBX) cannot generate desired offspring distribution

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I've found in some references that the offspring distribution of SBX must have the following shape for 2d vectors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQqNb.png)

However my implementation differs from that shape:

```
    par1 = [.2; .2];
par2 = [.8; .8];
eta = 15;
child1 = zeros(2,1);
child2 = child1;
hold on
for k = 1:100
    for i = 1:2
      u = rand;
      if (u<0.5)
          beta=(2*u)^(1/(eta+1));
      elseif (u>0.5)
          beta=(0.5/(1-u))^(1/(eta+1));
      elseif (u == .5)
          beta = 1;
      end
      c1(i) = 0.5*(par1(i)+par2(i)) - 0.5*beta*abs(par1(i)-par2(i));
      c2(i) = 0.5*(par1(i)+par2(i)) + 0.5*beta*abs(par1(i)-par2(i));

    end
    plot([c1(1), c2(1)], [c1(2), c2(2)], 'b.')

end
```

Here is my output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ3EO.png)
I think my implementation is correct, but i don't know why i cannot reach to that desired figure.

Answer (score -1):

the reason is that you need implement the reflections, check the nsga-ii code from the autor Deb.
There are two aditional actions: swap variables with a probability (0.5) and inherit parent variables directly with a certain probability.
Regards
Joel Chacón Castillo

Comment: Thank you for answer +1. Could you please provide a link for such implementation?

Comment: it is the [link code](https://www.iitk.ac.in/kangal/codes/nsga2/nsga2-gnuplot-v1.1.6.tar.gz) taken from the  [web](https://www.iitk.ac.in/kangal/codes.shtml)

Comment: I'm not the one who unvote your answer. Since I have less than 15 reputations, then my votes have been not displayed!

Comment: I would like to know the reason.., anyway I hope be usefull, (My first and last paricipation in this page...)